# Matlab pool warning

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, pool

*Warning: Found 1 pre-existing communicating job(s) created by pool that are running. You can use 'delete(myCluster.Jobs)' to remove all jobs created with profile local. To create 'myCluster' use 'myCluster = parcluster('local')'.*

**As soon as my I open matlabpool, I get this warning. I want to know what this means and how do I correct it. Also, can it affect the functioning of my code?**

Comment: Did you try doing as the message instructs?

Answer (score 1):

Run the command:

```
myCluster = parcluster('local')
delete(myCluster.Jobs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely forgetting to use matlabpool close after opening a matlabpool. If you don't close it, it remains active.